# My galaxy M10s stuck on download mode showing 'error verifying vbmata image'. Samsung galaxy M107f

Tags: custom-roms

I had rooted my galaxy m10s with eftsu to fix Imei NG status. then I wiped EFS but no longer started, just stack on samsung logo even if i wipe data. then I locked bootloader in download mode. and now it just keeps on download mode and shows 'error verifying vbmata image' and 'vbmata:no sign info'.
so guys please help me what shall i do?

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy